# When managing user secrets, must the Guid number in the project file be hidden?

Tags: asp.net-core

When managing user secrets, a guid number is written in the project file for reference, like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>pc183z95-o1t5-1245-u6z2-wfb29d1dq521</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Is it a security risk to expose this number in a public repository like GitHub? I understand that the purpose is to simply hide sensitive information by isolating them from the project. That way only someone with access to our local machine can see them. But what about this guid number? Must it be hidden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the user secrets ID itself does not need to be kept secret. It only serves the single purpose to identify the path where the the user secrets configuration source will look for the configuration when your application runs. On Windows, this path is `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<UserSecretsId>\secrets.json`. There, the `UserSecretsId` is only used as the name of a folder where the “secret” configuration file is stored.

A GUID is being used by default since that is just a safe bet that a newly created project will start with a fresh and empty folder instead of accidentally reusing the configurations from a different application. Technically, the ID is not limited to being a GUID though. Sometimes, the `UserSecretsId` is in the format `<ProjectName>-<GUID>` to make it easier to identify where the secrets are stored when you are in the root `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\` folder.

It is however also entirely practical to change this value to something of your liking, e.g. just a sufficiently unique name. This could be just your project name too if you can be somewhat certain that nobody else could come up with that name (or if there is a low chance that both projects are being worked on by the same developer causing a conflict).

Unless you put an actual secret into the value of `UserSecretsId`, sharing it will not impact the security of your secrets. You should note however, that despite the name *“user secrets”*, those secrets are not *really* protected. If you look into the folder where those `secrets.json` files are, you can see that this is just a folder with un-encrypted JSON files that contain your “secret” configuration.

The primary purpose of the user secrets configuration is to move *machine-local* configuration out of the project directory so that you do not accidentally commit this information into your project’s source control. This configuration is however not protected in any way and with access to your file system, the information can be read out very easily. The files being stored elsewhere makes it very easy *not to share* this information with others though which is how the user secrets configuration attempts to keep your configuration secret. – It’s a really simple but also very useful system but you should keep that in mind so that you do not expect things from it that it isn’t designed to do. For that reason, it’s also only enabled for development by default.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on your answer. I couldn't find something that addresses this very issue.